# Calculate an Integral using residue theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

How can I calculate following integral and prove equality using residue theorem?

$$\int_0^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt[n]{x^n -1}}dx = \frac{sin \frac{\pi}{n}}{\frac{\pi}{n}}$$

Comment: Your integrand is not real in general -- is this really what you're looking at? I don't think you can expect the result to be real. For example, if you take $n=2$, your answer seems to be wrong.

Comment: FYI, the integral equals $$\frac{\sqrt\pi e^{-\pi i /n}}{n}\frac{\Gamma(\frac1n)}{\Gamma(\frac1n+\frac12)}$$